# unable to install packages on GCP Ubuntu Instance

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

Respected trulies, I am trying to install VMI / Python on my Ubuntu VM instance on GCP, but getting the below messages.

```
jaipareek2502@pavansut:~$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'sudo apt-get update' or login as root user by using command (sudo -i).

Answer (score 0):

Please set root user by sudo - i then enter root password for initial set up then if you want to run same command under root it should work and if you exit root user then used sudo in front of your command